# Remove the Network Connections instrument and try again | Activity monitoring service not available on this device | XCODE 13 | IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, networking, emulation

**- I'm using XCODE on version 13.**

**- Application built on IONIC**

**- Application emulated on an IOS 15 emulator**

- ================================== ======== ================ +

**- What are the errors?**

When trying to evaluate application processes in  **"Activity Monitor "** I get the error:
**"Activity monitoring service not available on this device."**

When trying to evaluate network interactions on **"Network"** I get the error:
**"Remove the instrument from network connections and try again."**

**- What I need?**

I need to monitor how network interactions from an emulated app on an IOS in version 15.

**- How do I want to do this?**

I want to use **Network** for **Instruments** of the **Developer Tool **.

**- What am I doing?**

1 - I build the IONIC project

2 - I open the project using XCODE in version 13.

[Image of the project opened in XCODE] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG2be.jpg)

3 - Emulate the application

[Image of the emulated app] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74mmR.jpg)

3 - I open the **Instruments**. (**Xcode** ->** Open Developer Tool** -> **Instruments**)

[Image of the process of opening Instruments] [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2LJJ.jpg)

4 - Select **Network** and click on **Choose**

[Image of the process of opening the Network] [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKwCZ.jpg)

5 - I see error **"Remove the instrument from network connections and try again."**

[Image of the error when trying to open view a network interaction] [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5MGi.png)

**- Final questions**

What do I do to make the emulator active to visualize the network interactions and processes?

Why do I have these errors and how do I fix them?

Comment: same here, even i am developing using swift still got the error, such a shame from xcode